# Access class if class method is overwritten

Tags: ruby

Here is an external class which has its `class` method overwritten.

```
class Foo
  def class
    "fooo"
  end
end

class Boo < Foo
end

class Moo < Foo
end
```

Now I have an instance of the subclass. Is it possible to find out which class it belongs to?

```
foo.class # currently returns 'fooo', I want get Boo or Moo.
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use [`instance_method`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Module.html#method-i-instance_method) to grab the `class` method from somewhere safe (such as `Object`) as an [`UnboundMethod`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/UnboundMethod.html), bind that unbound method to your instance, and then call it. For example:

```
class_method = Object.instance_method(:class)
# #<UnboundMethod: Object(Kernel)#class> 

class_method.bind(Boo.new).call
# Boo 

class_method.bind(Moo.new).call
# Moo 

class_method.bind(Foo.new).call
# Foo
```

Of course, if you've also replaced `Object#class` (or `Kernel#class`) then all bets are off and you're in a whole new world of pain and confusion.

Answer (score 5):

I prefer @Stefan’s and @muistooshort's solutions, but here's an alternative.

```
class Foo
  def class
    "foo"
  end
end

class Boo < Foo
end

class Who < Boo
  def class
    "who"
  end
end
```

```
boo = Boo.new
boo.method(:class).super_method.call
  #=> Boo

who = Who.new
who.method(:class).super_method.call
  #=> "foo"
who.method(:class).super_method.super_method.call
  #=> Who
```

More generally:

```
def my_class(obj)
  m = obj.method(:class)
  until m.owner == Kernel do
    m = m.super_method
  end
  m.call
end

my_class(boo)
  #=> Boo 
my_class(who)
  #=> Who
```

See [Method#super_method](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Method.html#method-i-super_method).

Answer (score 5):

An object's class also happens to be the [`superclass`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Class.html#method-i-superclass) of its [`singleton_class`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Object.html#method-i-singleton_class):

```
Boo.new.singleton_class.superclass
#=> Boo

Moo.new.singleton_class.superclass
#=> Moo

Foo.new.singleton_class.superclass
#=> Boo
```

Comment: You could also use `class << Boo.new ; superclass ; end` if you are worried that `singleton_class` might be overridden.

Comment: Cut-and-paste typo: `Foo.new.singleton_class.superclass #=> Foo`.

Answer (score 3):

This solution is a little hacky, but overriding `class` is pretty hacky in itself, so when in Rome, do as Romans do:

```
class Foo
  def class
    'fooo'
  end
end

class Boo < Foo
end

boo = Boo.new
=> #<Boo:0x00007fd2361feba8>

boo.class
=> "fooo"

boo.inspect
=> "#<Boo:0x00007fd2361feba8>"

klass = boo.inspect.split(':').reject(&:empty?)[0..-2].join('::').sub('#<', '')
=> "Boo"

boo.is_a?(Kernel.const_get(klass))
=> true
```

This also works for classes in a module:

```
module Bar
  class Foo
    def class
      'fooo'
    end
  end

  class Boo < Foo
  end
end

boo = Bar::Boo.new
=> #<Bar::Boo:0x00007fe5a20358b0>

boo.class
=> "fooo"

boo.inspect
=> "#<Bar::Boo:0x00007fe5a20358b0>"

klass = boo.inspect.split(':').reject(&:empty?)[0..-2].join('::').sub('#<', '')
=> "Bar::Boo"

boo.is_a?(Kernel.const_get(klass))
=> true
```